c# blazor assetsCache.ts
При первом знакомстве с blazor webassembly после запуска "хелловорда" обнаружил в браузере загрузку и выполнение функций скриптов, расположенных по адресам
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/9d5a6a9aa463d6d10b0b0ba6d5982cc82f363dc3/src/mono/browser/runtime/loader/assetsCache.ts
и
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/9d5a6a9aa463d6d10b0b0ba6d5982cc82f363dc3/src/mono/browser/runtime/debug.ts
Вероятно, ссылки на скрипты встраиваются приложением в страницу для работы/отладки webassembly.
Место, где подключаются эти скрипты я нашел: после сборки проекта создаются файлы "bin\Debug\net9.0\wwwroot_framework\dotnet.js.map" и "bin\Debug\net9.0\wwwroot_framework\dotnet.runtime.js.map" и в них есть ссылки на вышеупомянутые скрипты.
Но как и чем собираются конкретно эти .map файлы - я не могу понять.
Мне хотелось бы избавиться от ссылок на сторонние ресурсы в приложении(можно скачать эти скрипты локально, если нужно), но я не понимаю как и где они включаются в страницу.
В отладчике Хрома на вкладке network нет никаких обращений к адресу "https://raw.githubusercontent.com"

Гугление ничего не дало.

Я выяснил: 1. опубликованное приложение не отправляет клиентов по внешним ссылкам на https://raw.githubusercontent.com. 2. Для облегчения отладки .NET 9 SDK может подгружать исходные коды библиотек из репозиториев GitHub (и д.р.). Вероятно, базовые настройки хранятся в конфигах "sdk\9.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub\build\Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub.props", но попытки их изменить приводили лишь к невозможности сборки проекта. Видимо, можно отключить эти настройки где-то в другом месте.
